# Configure Application load balancer to route http to https in Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my Aws elastic beanstalk environment i have configured application load balancer. i Would like to route all HTTP traffic to HTTPS for all paths in my domain. i have tried appending https listener config file with the application code(laravel), but still my domain is listening to http only . My goal is to create an https listener rule that will point to existing http target group. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html) document:

> To update your Elastic Beanstalk environment to use HTTPS, you need to
>   configure an HTTPS listener for the load balancer in your environment.
>
> You can use the Elastic Beanstalk console to configure a secure
>   listener and assign the certificate.

Comment: Thanks, Venkatesh...For classic load balancer, we could add a certificate from the Elastic Beanstalk console.But for other load balancers, you need to add configuration files through EB CLI. Can you help me out if you have tried that?

Comment: @vineethc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html#add-listener-cli